# Replacing javascript alert with jQuery UI / Dialog

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How can I change what I am using which is javascript alert to use a jQuery UI / dialog. I have been trying to change my script over to use a dialog with no success. I want to use something better than alert to create the popup for my calendar. So I was thinking of a dialog but if there is something better I would be interested it also.

This is my fullcalendar code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

             eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Name:  ' + calEvent.title + '\n' + "Start Date/Time: " +  $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss TT') + '\n' + 'End Date/Time:  ' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss TT') + '\n' +  'Address:  ' + calEvent.address1 +  '\n' + 'Apt/Suite:  ' + calEvent.address2 + '\n' + 'City/Sate/Zip:  ' + calEvent.city + ' ' + calEvent.state + ' ' + calEvent.zip + '\n' + 'Home Phone:  ' + calEvent.hphone + '\n' + 'Cell Phone:   ' + calEvent.cphone + '\n' + 'Work Phone:  ' + calEvent.wphone + '\n' + 'Email:  ' + calEvent.email + '\n' + 'Order Number:   ' + calEvent.ordern);
            },
         events: "json_events.php", 


         loading: function(bool) { 
            if (bool) $('#loading').show(); 
            else $('#loading').hide(); 
         } 

      }); 

   });
```

This is how I send my json code to the calendar

> $events = array(); foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM `signings` WHERE
>   `pid` = '$pid' AND `done`= 0") as $row) {
>
> ```
> $title = $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
> $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['id'];
> $eventsArray['ordern'] =  $row['ordern'];
> $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
> //$eventsArray['url'] = "eventinfo.php?id=$id";
> $eventsArray['start'] = $row['signstart'];
> $eventsArray['end'] = $row['signend'];
> $eventsArray['address1'] = $row['street1'];
> $eventsArray['address2'] = $row['street2'];
> $eventsArray['city'] = $row['city'];
> $eventsArray['state'] = $row['state'];
> $eventsArray['zip'] = $row['zip'];
> $eventsArray['hphone'] = $row['hphone'];
> $eventsArray['cphone'] = $row['cphone'];
> $eventsArray['wphone'] = $row['wphone'];
> $eventsArray['email'] = $row['email'];
> $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
> $eventsArray['color'] = "#7B1616";
> $eventsArray['textColor'] = "#FFFFFF";
>
> $events[] = $eventsArray; }
> ```
>
> echo json_encode($events);

Answer (score 0):

Caveats: I used jqAlert() as the function name and jqAlert() is not truly modal in the same way the JS alert() function is modal.  The way the example code is setup in your question you would not need a true modal dialog, but it would not surprise me if that was an unwritten expectation.

```
function jqAlert(msg) {
    console.log("Alert: " + msg);
    $('<div id="sfUI-Dialog-Alert" title="Message from Web Application" style="font-size: 0.8em"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>' + msg + '</div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 222,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 444
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 333
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small library to make this easy.

https://github.com/Scimonster/jquery-ui-alert

It's simple, but can be customized.

Answer (score 0):

I would use qtip which fullcalendar has an [example](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) of how to use.

After installing [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) (qtip no longer actively developed) your code would look this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

             eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Name:  ' + calEvent.title + '\n' + "Start Date/Time: " +  $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss TT') + '\n' + 'End Date/Time:  ' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss TT') + '\n' +  'Address:  ' + calEvent.address1 +  '\n' + 'Apt/Suite:  ' + calEvent.address2 + '\n' + 'City/Sate/Zip:  ' + calEvent.city + ' ' + calEvent.state + ' ' + calEvent.zip + '\n' + 'Home Phone:  ' + calEvent.hphone + '\n' + 'Cell Phone:   ' + calEvent.cphone + '\n' + 'Work Phone:  ' + calEvent.wphone + '\n' + 'Email:  ' + calEvent.email + '\n' + 'Order Number:   ' + calEvent.ordern);
            },
         events: "json_events.php", 
         //New code here:
         eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.qtip({
               content: event.description
            });
         },

         loading: function(bool) { 
            if (bool) $('#loading').show(); 
            else $('#loading').hide(); 
         } 

      }); 

   });
```

Comment: I changed my code to look like this but it did not work correctly. I stuck my data at the top of the calendar and it only displayed 1 of three and it was not clickable. So then I took the sample from FullCalendar docs and it did the same thing. In the qTip documents it says they recommend jQuery 1.3.2. Do you think that would have anything to do with it I am using jquery-1.11.0

Comment: That may be it. Try installing qtip2 as qtip is no longer supported. I updated the post with the new link.